# Minimum cost of receiver-transmitter network

Tags: algorithm

Let us assume that we have `n` devices, `n` even number . Each device can work either as a transmitter (`T`) or as a receiver (`R`).   For every device `i`, we are given 2 numbers, `Ti` and `Ri`. `Ti` is the cost in case the device works as transmitter and `Ri` the cost in case it works as a receiver . We also know that `Ti>=Ri` for every `i`.

*Our task is to choose exactly `n/2` transmitters and `n/2` receivers , in a way that we achieve minimum cost.*  (the final answer is the minimum cost only)

Additional restriction:  Transmiters transmit always from left to right .
That means that we can have  sequence `TTTRRR`, `TTRTRR`, `TRTRTR`, etc  but not `RTTTRR`. We can never encounter more receivers than transmitters at any point.

Which is the most suitable algorithm for this task?

Example :  we have 4 devices .  T1=9 ,R1=6 , T2=6 ,R2=2 ,T3=8 ,R3=1 ,T4=5 ,R4=3

- Possible solution 1 : `TTRR`   total cost : 9+6+1+3 =19
- Possible solution 2 : `TRTR`   total cost : 9+2+8+3 =22

Optimal solution : `TTRR`, cost 19.

So final answer is 19.

Comment: How big `n` can be? Is *brute force* algorithm an option?

Comment: There is no restriction considering n ,it can be a huge number .  Brute force is definitely an option , but I hope that we will be able to find something faster .

Answer (score 1):

An `O(n^2)` dynamic programming solution is pretty straightforward.

Let `f(prefix_len, transmitters)` be the optimal cost one can obtain in such a way that `prefix_len` elements have already been processed, the prefix is correct and the number of transmitters is exactly `transmitters` more than the number of receivers (that is, it's a "balance" in some sense).

The base case is `f(0, 0) = 0` (an empty prefix is free).
The transitions are as follows `f(prefix_len, transmitters) + T[i] -> f(prefix_len, transmitters + 1)` (we make the current element a transmitter). If `transmitters > 0`, there's also a transition `f(prefix_len, transmitters) + R[i] -> f(prefix_len + 1, transmitters - 1)` (we make it a receiver).

The answer is `f(n, 0)` (that is, we used all the elements and the number of transmitters is equal to the number of recievers).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a commented, recursive JavaScript implementation of kraskevich's outline:

```js
var ts = [9,6,8,5],
    rs = [6,2,1,3],
    n = ts.length;

// returns cost from index i forward, with t more transmitters than receivers
function f(i,t){
  // last one must be a receiver
  if (i === n - 1) return rs[n-1];

  return Math.min(
    // avoid having more transmitters than we can receive
    t + 1 <= (n - i + 1) >> 1 ? ts[i] + f(i + 1,t + 1) : Infinity,

    // don't encounter more receivers than transmitters
    t > 0 ? rs[i] + f(i + 1,t - 1) : Infinity
  );
}

console.log(f(0,0)); // 19
```